# how do i handle security within my microservice architecture?

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, microservices, vpc, api-gateway

In my webapp architecture i have an api gateway which proxies requests to my microservices, also there is a a common microservice which other microservices can query via rest api. All of these run on node servers.
i want the microservices to only be approachable from the api gateway, besides the common server which can also be approachable from the other microservices. what is the best network architecture to make this happen and do i need to handle authentication between the servers in some way?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Security needs to be handled at multiple layers and as such its a really broad topic. I will however share some pointers which you can explore further.

First thing first any security comes at a cost. And it's a trade off that you need to do.

If you can ensure that services are available only to the other services and API gateway, then you can delegate application layer security to API gateway and strip the security headers at API gateway itself and continue to have free communication between services. It is like creating restricted zone with ip restrictions (or other means on from where can service be accessed), and api gateway or reverse proxy handling all the external traffic. This will allow you to concentrate on few services as far as security is concerned. Point that you should note here is that you will be losing on authorization part as well but you can retain it if you want to.

If you are using AWS you need to look into security groups and VPN etc to set up a secure layer.

A part of security is also to ensure the service is accessible all the time and is not susceptible to DDOS. API gateways do have a means of safeguarding against such threats.

Answer (score 0):

For the ‘API gateway’ front-end authentication you could use [OATH2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) and for the back-end part you can use [OpenID connect](http://openid.net/connect/) which will allow you to use a key value that is relevant to the user, like for example a uuid and use this to set access control at the Microservice level, behind the API Gateway.

You can find in the next link further information about [OpenID connect](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect) authentication.